# Why isn't this while loop exiting?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I wrote a console program to help me test a function library I coded. Part of it is this piece of code:

```
char insertChoice[2] = {'9'};

while (insertChoice[0] != '0')
{
    cout << "\nEnter a string:\n";
    char insertStringInput[256];
    cin.getline(insertStringInput, 255);

    char insertChoice[2];
    insertChoice[0] = '9';

    cout << "\nWhere would you like to insert the substring?\n\n
             1) At the beginning of the string\n
             2) At the end of the string\n\nInput: ";
    cin >> insertChoice;
    cin.ignore();

    while (insertChoice[0] != '1' && insertChoice[0] != '2')
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid input.\nWhere would you like to insert the substring?\n\n
                 1) At the beginning of the string\n
                 2) At the end of the string\n\nInput: ";
        cin >> insertChoice;
        cin.ignore();
    }

    cout << "\nEnter the substring you would like to insert: ";
    char insertSubstring[256];
    cin.getline(insertSubstring, 255);

    std::string used = "", substr = "";
    used += insertStringInput;
    substr += insertSubstring;

    char insertOutputChoice[2];
    insertOutputChoice[0] = '1';

    if (insertChoice[0] == '1')
        insertOutput(insertInBeginning(used, substr));
    else
        insertOutput(insertInEnd(used, substr));

    cin >> insertOutputChoice;
    cin.ignore();

    if (insertOutputChoice[0] == '1')
    {
        ofstream outfile("logfile.txt", ios::app);

        outfile << "Test type: Insert Substring\n";
        outfile << "Test carried out on: " << __DATE__ << "; " << __TIME__ <<"\n";
        outfile << "PARAMETERS:\n";
        outfile << "usedString: \"" << insertStringInput << "\"\n";
        outfile << "insertString: \"" << insertSubstring << "\"\n";
        outfile << "function used: " 
                << (insertChoice[0]=='1'?"insertInBeginning":"insertInEnd") 
                << "\nOUTPUT:\n";
        outfile << "\"" 
                << (insertChoice[0]=='1'?insertInBeginning(used, substr):insertInEnd(used, substr)) 
                << "\"\n\n";

        outfile.close();

        cout << "\nWould you like to do another string insertion test? [y/n]: ";
        char insertConfirm[2];
        insertConfirm[0] = ' ';

        while (tolower(insertConfirm[0]) != 'y' 
               && tolower(insertConfirm[0] != 'n'))
        {
            cin >> insertConfirm;
            cin.ignore();
            if (tolower(insertConfirm[0]) != 'y' 
                && tolower(insertConfirm[0] != 'n'))
                cout << "\nInvalid input. 
                         Would you like to do another string insertion test? [y/n]: ";
        }

        if (insertConfirm[0] == 'n')
            insertChoice[0] = '0';
    }
}
```

However, the `while (insertChoice[0] != '0')` loop does not exit when the user types in `insertOutputChoice` as 1, regardless of whether the user types in `insertConfirm` as `y` or `n` even though it is supposed to exit when `insertConfirm` is typed in as `n`.

`insertOutput` looks as looks as follows:

```
void insertOutput(std::string substrOut)
{
    cout << "\nThe new string generated is:\n";
    cout << substrOut;

    cout << "\n\n1) Generate a log file of this test\n";
    cout << "2) Insert another substring into a string\n\n";
    cout << "0) Finish testing string insertion\n\n\n";

    cout << "Input: ";
}
```

Please excuse the messy, unoptimized code. My first priority is to get this done, and I usually leave optimization until last.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger and examined the variable's values?

Comment: Yes. The `if (insertConfirm[0] == 'n')
            insertChoice[0] = '0';` does change the value of insertChoice, but when the while criteria is evaluated, insertChoice[0] changes back to '9' until the code inside the while starts executing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the while loop you create a new `insertChoice` array. And it hides external one. So when you modify values in this array, external one remains unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may also be an issue with the if statement at the end of the code. Have you tried this while inputting in both upper and lower case? When checking for a valid input you are converting to lowercase to check but not when checking if the response is 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line 9:

```
char insertChoice[2];
```

Comment: Please give an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code, are you sure it's compiling correctly?

First, there are 2 `insertChoice` declarations

```
char insertChoice[2] = {'9'};    // <------- 1ˢᵗ
```

and in the while loop:

```
    char insertChoice[2];        // <------- 2ⁿᵈ
    insertChoice[0] = '9';
```

The compiler should warn you about that. If not you must enable warnings with the appropriate options of your compiler (`/W3` for cl, `-Wall -Wpedantic` for gcc...). Never compile without warnings

---

Second, the following string has syntax error

```
cout << "\nWhere would you like to insert the substring?\n\n
         1) At the beginning of the string\n
         2) At the end of the string\n\nInput: ";
```

If you want a line break in the string you must use an escape right before the new line character

```
cout << "\nWhere would you like to insert the substring?\n\n\
1) At the beginning of the string\n\
2) At the end of the string\n\nInput: ";
```

or use multiple string literals like this

```
cout << "\nWhere would you like to insert the substring?\n\n"
        "1) At the beginning of the string\n"
        "2) At the end of the string\n\nInput: ";
```

Consecutive literals will be automatically combined into one by the compiler

In C++-0x life is a lot easier with [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) where **embedded quotes or newlines** are possible

```
cout << R"(
Where would you like to insert the substring?


1) At the beginning of the string
2) At the end of the string

Input: )";
```